# How to use formulas with drop-down and checkboxes for easier grading e.g. dynamic comments and enum-like drop-downs work with `switch` function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

## [Quick Comments Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KEsPhejYwHL3myPWFq2UktwZY9EGWBMTZbpgjYkkLn8/edit?usp=sharing)

### Sheet Preview

#### M.W.E.

The "Example Table" demonstrated the desired *functionality*. That is:

- checkboxes append comments to notes
- drop down is linked to grade

[image: main table]

#### Attempts

This table shows my attempts to create enum-like drop-downs with the `SWITCH` function. While it works, it doesn't achieve the desired effect of allows a dynamic number of `(condition, value)` pairs by specifying a range. I also try some combinations of `MAP`, `LOOKUP`, `CELL`, etc with lackluster results:
[image: formulas table]

### Context

I have a sheet that looks sort of like the above images. Here
is the formula I am using to aggregate the checkbox comments:

```golang
// Dynamic comments construction
= JOIN(" ", 
  CONCAT(D13, "."),                              // Dropdown value
  CONCAT(CONCAT(UPPER($H$12), ": "), H13),       // Notes
  IF(E13, CONCATENATE($E$12, ": ", $E$11), ""),  // Mistake 1
  IF(F13, CONCATENATE($F$12, ": ", $F$11), ""),  // Mistake 2
  IF(G13, CONCATENATE($G$12, ": ", $G$11), "")   // Mistake 3
)
```

and here is the forumla I am using to calculate the grade:

```golang
// Enum-Like switch. How can I map over the enum values?
= SWITCH(D13:D16, 
  "Amazing", 10,             // Enum.AMAZING
  "One small thing", 7.5,    // Enum.ONE_SMALL_THING
  "Not quite right", 5,      // Enum.NOT_QUITE_RIGHT
  "Needs improvement", 2.5   // Enum.NEEDS_IMPROVEMENT
)
```

For those wondering, here are the "Lookup function" attempts:

```golang
= LOOKUP(C33, C26:C30)
= CELL("address", LOOKUP(C33, C26:C30))
= MAP(C33, LAMBDA(cell, OFFSET(LOOKUP(cell, C26:C30), 0, 2)))
```

### Questions

Is there perhaps a better way to create a drop-down menu for comments / grade tiers?
Is there a way to use checkboxes to concatenate the comments with shorted headers? e.g. Mapping over the `concat` statements as well as maybe using comments or notes to hold the comment to add rather than using a different cell? `CELL("content", A1)` doesn't support "notes" or "comments" as an `info_type`...

### Bonus

It would also be nice to have some guidance on `NamedFunction`s that can be used to automatically create and use these kinds of cells. e.g.

```golang
DROPDOWN(cell, enum_vals, info_type = "index", [(info_type_name, enum_vals), ...])
/**
 * @param cell: The reference to the cell to evaluate.
 * @param enum_vals: The reference range of the original enum values
 * @param info_type (optional): The type of information to return about the enum values. 
        Defaults to index of the matched enum value.


 * @param info_type_name (optional): A string cell representing the type of information to return about the enum values.
 * @param enum_vals (optional): A range of cells representing the original enum values.
*/
```

So for the images above (see "Attempts" section):

- "Perfect", ..., "Needs work" would be the first `enum_vals` range
- "Comment 1", ..., "Comment 5" would be an optional `enum_vals` range
- 10, ..., 2 would be an optional `enum_vals` range
- "Associated Comments" would be an `info_type_name`
- "Associated Number" would be an `info_type_name`

Therefore we could make up some example calls like

```golang
// dummy table
// | Question  | --- | GradeEnum | Comments    | Values |
// | --------  | --- | --------- | ----------- | ------ |
// | "Almost"  | --- | "Perfect" | "Comment 1" |     10 |
// |    ...    | --- |    ...    |    ...      |  ...   |


// lets pretend A2 is cell with a dropdown. and the enum values 
// ("Perfect", ...) are in B2:B6 for convenience
DROPDOWN(A2, B2:B6)             --> 2 // assuming 0-indexed
DROPDOWN(A2, B2:B6, "index")    --> 2 // assuming 0-indexed
DROPDOWN(A2, B2:B6, C1, C2:C6)  --> "Comment 1"
DROPDOWN(A2, B2:B6, D1, D2:D6)  --> 6

DROPDOWN(A2, B2:B6, "Comments", C2:C6)  --> "Comment 1"
DROPDOWN(A2, B2:B6, "Values", D2:D6)    --> 6
```

Comment: Could you show your ``lookup`` attempt?

Comment: This looks like a copy of [How to use drop-down and checkboxes for easier grading](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/241169242). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Comment: @doubleunary Yes, I originally posted on Google. I updated my question and then posted it here as I noticed that it looked like users couldn't see the images I posted. So I just took down the google thread. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: @TheMaster yes, added.

Comment: There is no need to delete threads because of duplication. Just [Be Forthright](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Comment: @doubleunary thanks you for helping enforce community guidelines. I won't repost since I already deleted it. Thank you for your time and kindness :)

Comment: Seems like you're just looking for xlookup. For grade numbers:  `=xlookup(D13,GradeTiersRange, Associated number range)`

Comment: @TheMaster thank you that certainly helps but what about the checkbox comment concat?

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing [links like spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455), which make the question useless for others or [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which are hard to copy. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.